# Python : encode a message entered by user as per below conditions

Tags: python

I am beginner in Python.

For every word in the sentence,

1. If the word starts with a vowel, encode it as the first and last letter of the word.
2. If the word starts with a consonant, remove all vowels from it.

I can code one of the above condition , but not both together. Not able to comprehend it.

for example : Please enter your text:  `The quick brown fox used to sleep inside this box`
Encoded output should be  `Th qck brwn fx ud t slp ie ths bx`

**The Code:**

```
vowel = "aeiou"
a = input("")
b = a.split()

result1=''
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] not in vowel:
        result1+=a[i]
print(result1)

words = []
for i in b:
    words.append(i)

for word in words:
    if word[0] in 'aeiou':
        word = word[0] + word[len(word)-1]
        print(word)
```

Comment: To learn how to improve your question, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please show the code you've tried

Comment: don't post images of your code, I'm going to type it to try

Comment: you create a variable `vowel` but you use a literal copy of it.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: shorter `words = b.copy()` but I would use directly `b` instead of `words` in `for word in b:`

Answer (score 1):

Removing vowels can be performed by the *sub* function of the *re* module. The other encoding is trivial if you remember that for a string S the last character is S[-1]

Try this:

```
from re import compile

SENTENCE = "The quick brown fox used to sleep inside this box"
VS = set(VOWELS := "aeiouAEIOU")
PATTERN = compile(rf"[{VOWELS}]")

def encode(sentence):
    output = []
    for word in sentence.split():
        if word[0] in VS:
            output.append(word[0] + word[-1])
        else:
            output.append(PATTERN.sub("", word))
    return output

print(*encode(SENTENCE))
```

**Output:**

```
Th qck brwn fx ud t slp ie ths bx
```

It's unclear what the encoding of a one-letter word that's just a vowel (e.g., "a" or "I") should look like

Comment: @CiaPan Thank you. I messed up an edit to the code. Now fixed. I was using the wrong sentence

Comment: OK, thumb up. :)